# Love2d Rotating an image

Tags: image, lua, rotation, love2d

I would like to rotate an image in Love2D.
I have found a documentation on love2d.org: https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.rotate
But I can't seem to get it to work when I try to load an image.
Heres my code:

```
local angle = 0

function love.load()
    g1 = love.graphics.newImage("1.png") 
end

function love.draw()
    width = 100
    height = 100
    love.graphics.translate(width/2, height/2)
    love.graphics.rotate(angle)
    love.graphics.translate(-width/2, -height/2)
    love.graphics.draw(g1, width, height)
end

function love.update(dt)
    love.timer.sleep(10)
    angle = angle + dt * math.pi/2
    angle = angle % (2*math.pi)
end
```

Could anyone show me an simple example of rotating an image in love2d?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.draw

You may be better off using the fourth argument, shown as 'r' to rotate images, such as:

```
love.graphics.draw(image, x, y, math.pi/4)
```

It's not worth the trouble of using the translate functions for a single draw, and keeping those for when you're batching many draws at once.

Comment: "It's also a fairly bad idea to use the translate functions" - on what grounds do you claim this?

Comment: I recommend removing that part of the answer. The translate functions work very well. They are just more cumbersome to draw images than just using the parameters in ´love.graphics.draw´.

Comment: I did mention there's a lot of times it comes in useful. I'm simply pointing out it can muck up a lot of things if you're offsetting the entire coordinate system.

Comment: Of course, if you're using push and pop as Deco suggests, then there's no real difference and it could make your code a lot simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Your code worked perfectly for me, aside from a small unrelated issue ([`love.timer.sleep`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.timer.sleep) uses seconds in LÖVE 0.8.0).

We will be able to help you better, and perhaps reproduce your error, if you provide us with more information.
When you say

> I can't seem to get it to work when I try to load an image

..what is the result?
Is the image a white box? Does the application crash? Is there nothing on the screen?

All of these imply a image loading issue, rather than a rotation issue. Although, it could be the case that the image is rotating off of the screen.

---

If you continue to use `translate`, `rotate`, and `scale` (which is usually a good idea), I recommend you take a look at the [`push`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.push) and [`pop`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.pop) functions.
They allow you to 'stack' transformations so you can render sub elements.

Example uses are rendering a GUI (each child pushes its translation and then renders the children) and drawing sprites on a scrolling map (the camera translates the entire map and then does `for entity in entities do push() entity:draw() pop() end`. Each entity can translate and rotate in local coordinates (0,0 = centre of sprite)).

Comment: The program just crashes. You see one second the image and then it crashes. And i will look into push and pop

Comment: Eventually i got it to work, but alil diffrent i used this: http://pastebin.com/DjQNej9e But for some reason when i want to keep rotating the image it simply crashes

Comment: `while true do stuff end` will freeze your program. The loop will run for ever and it will never reach the end of your `love.draw` function, meaning an image will never be presented to the screen (and your application will lock up).

Answer (score 1):

```
love.graphics.draw( drawable, x, y, r, sx, sy, ox, oy, kx, ky )
```

the R is the rotation.. why don't you just set it to a variable and change it as you please? ... I'm new to programming so I may be wrong but this is how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Example of rotating at center of image using LOVE 11.3 (Mysterious Mysteries):

```
function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(img, 400,300, wheel.r, wheel.sx, wheel.sy, wheel.w / 2,  wheel.h / 2)
end

function love.update(dt)
    wheel.r = wheel.r + dt  
end

function love.load()
    wheel = {x = 0, y = 0, w = 0, h = 0, sx = 0.5, sy = 0.5, r = 0, image = "wheel.png"}
    img = love.graphics.newImage(wheel.image)
    wheel.w = img:getWidth()
    wheel.h = img:getHeight()               
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Normaly the axis for rotating is the upper left corner. To center the axis to the middle of an image you have to use the parameters after the `r` parameter to half of width and half of height of the image.